# UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait in Xamarin

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, uikit, xamarin

What is the Xamarin equivalent of the following iOS UIKit function:

```
UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(UIInterfaceOrientation orientation)
```

More generally, knowing the iOS name of a function, is there a lookup somewhere to find the Xamarin name of the same function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait` is a [macro](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/macro/UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait) (not a function) defined as:

```
#define UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(orientation) \
   ((orientation) == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || \
   (orientation) == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
```

In general the macros, being simple, are not implemented in `monotouch.dll`.

For **functions** (not methods) you'll generally find them, in a more object-oriented fashion, in the related type. E.g.

```
CGContextRef UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext (void);
```

would be:

```
CGContext UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext ();
```

For ObjC methods you'll generally find a C# method named after the selector (but there are some exceptions)

You can also use the *search* box of MonoDoc (from Xamarin Studio, Help, API Documentation) and paste the selector name. It will move you directly to the right method.

E.g. paste `fontNamesForFamilyName` and you'll get **MonoTouch.UIKit.UIFont.FontNamesForFamilyName Method** documentation.